# Components of signed measure are greater than or equal to positive and negative variation of the signed measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$, where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are measures. Show that $\mu_1 \geq \mu^+$ and $\mu_2 \geq \mu^-$.

Comment: Are $\mu^+,\mu^-$ from the Hahn decomposition?

Comment: The main flaw in your solution attempt is that you haven't used the definition of $\mu^+,\mu^-$ (Hahn decomposition) at all. More specifically, you seem to think that $\mu(E) \ge 0$ implies $\mu^+(E)=\mu(E)$ and $\mu^-(E)=0$ (i.e., you are conflating with the similarly notated "positive part of function $f$ is $f^+(x) = \max\{f(x), 0\}$"), which is not really how $\mu^+$ is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $N,P$ a Hahn decomposition. Considering $\mu^+,\mu^-$ the positive and negative variations of $\mu$ we have by definition that for every set $E \in \mathbf{X}$
$$
\mu^+(E)=\mu(E \cap P)=\mu_1(E \cap P)-\mu_2(E \cap P) \leq \mu_1(E \cap P) \leq \mu_1(E)
$$
and
$$
\mu^-(E)=-\mu(E \cap N)=\mu_2(E \cap N)-\mu_1(E \cap N) \leq \mu_2(E \cap N) \leq \mu_2(E).
$$