# Equivalent formulation of the variation of a signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

I am going through Bogachev's book on Measure Theory, and having read the definition of variation of measures I am trying to grasp what it is doing. I have the following doubt.

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure and define its variation as $|\nu|:=\nu^++ \nu^-$ where $(\nu^+,\nu^-)$ is the Hahn-Jordan decomposition of $\nu$ (e.g. p. 176 in Bogachev's book). If $\nu$ is given by $\nu=m_1-m_2$, where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are two positive finite measures, is it true that $|\nu|=m_1 + m_2$?

I could not prove the equality, however since $m_1\geq\nu^+$ and $m_2\geq\nu^-$ (e.g. [Components of signed measure are greater than or equal to positive and negative variation of the signed measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921022/components-of-signed-measure-are-greater-than-or-equal-to-positive-and-negative)) it seems that $|\nu|\leq m_1 + m_2$ holds. Is the other inequality true?

Comment: Consider the case $m_1 = m_2$.

Comment: I see - thanks. So cannot surely be true in general.
I can also foresee that even if $m_1\neq m_2$ but $m_1$ and $m_2$ give the same measure to some set $E$, then the inequality will fail there (?)

What if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are so different in that e.g. they both admit densities $f$ and $g$ such that $f\neq g$ everywhere?

Comment: Actually the equality $|v| = m_1 + m_2$ is true if and only if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are mutually singular.

Comment: I see - many thanks!